# Array Join ish operator in Rx

Tags: rxjs, reactive

I have an `Observable<EntityId[]>` and can for each EntityId get an `Observable<Entity>`. I want to transform it into an `Observable<Entity[]>`. The following solves it in a simple manner:

```
idsStream
    .Select(ids => ids
        .Select(id => StreamEntity(id))
        .CombineLatest())
    .Switch()
```

The problem is that each time the idsStream emits some new ids, every entity subscription will be closed, and new ones will be opened. I only want to close the Observables that no longer is contained in the `EntityId[]` and open new streams for the added ids.

It seems to me, that there should be an operator for this, but I can not find anything. Does anyone know such an operator, or should I compose/implement my own. If so, the following seems like an idea

```
// Only select for new elements and reuses former values
SelectAndKeep: Observable<TIn[]> -> (TIn -> TOut) -> Observable<TOut[]>

// Only subscribes/unsubscribe to new/removed observables
SwitchKeepAndCombineLatest: Observable<Observable<T>[]> -> Observable<T[]>

Observable<EntityId[]> idsStream

Observable<Observable<Entity>[]> entitiesStreamStream = 
    idsStream.SelectAndKeep(id => StreamEntity(id))

Observable<Entity[]> entitiesStream = entitiesStreamStream
    .SwitchKeepAndCombineLatest()
```

Any thoughts or experiences with this scenario? It seems quite generic and thus a good solution should exist...

Comment: hi Andreas and welcome to stackoverflow, in order to prupose you the must elegant solution. Please consider posting executable code whitch will be the base for the pruposal. in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) is right place to prupose it. No need to provide entire code, just dummy observable with pointed issue.

Answer (score 0):

base on my understanding of your question, i prupose you this implementation :

```
interface Entity {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
const entities: Entity[] = [{id: 1, title: 'foo1'}, {id: 2, title: 'foo2'}, {id: 3, title: 'foo3'}];

const entities$ = of(entities); // Observable of Entity[]

const ids$ = of([1,2], [1,3]); // Observable of ids.

ids$.pipe(mergeMap(ids => { 
  // Transform collection of id to collection of entity
  return entities$.pipe(map((entities) => {
      // from whole collection of entity, let keep what is present on ids.
      return entities.filter(entity => ids.findIndex(id => entity.id === id) !== -1);
  }));
})).subscribe(console.log);
```

`entities$` Observable should be Hot observable (like BehaviorSubject) in order to always receive last entities available on your store. `mergeMap` parallel merge and map each new data on your `ids$` stream to collection of entities filtered by your original ids collection.

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fmrbbz?devtoolsheight=60)